# Как отделить событие на родительском элементе от событии на дочернем?

Tags: javascript

```js
const parent = document.getElementById('parent');
const child1 = document.getElementById('child1');
parent.addEventListener('copy', (e) => {
  console.log('bubbling');
  console.log(e.target); // Тут указан child1 в качестве target
});

child1.addEventListener('copy', (e) => {
  console.log('copied!');
});
```

```html
<a href="#" id="parent">
  <span id="child1">asdasd</span>
  <span id="child2">qweqweqw</span>
</a>
```

Хочу сделать так: если был выделен и скопирован дочерний элемент, то его обработчик события запускается. А вот если был выделен и скопирован родитель (куда входит в т.ч. дочерний элемент 1, но еще и дочерний 2), то обработчик события для дочернего1 не должен запускаться. Можно было бы смотреть на e.target, но при выделении и копировании родительского контейнера в качестве target устанавливается его первый ребенок - почему так, просто ставится в качестве самого глубокого элемента первый ребенок? При том не важно, с какой стороны выделять и копировать. Можно ли как-то изловчиться?

Уточняю, при копировании дочернего1 должен вылазить алерт, при выделении и копировании родителя (вместе с дочерним1, но и с другими элементами), алерт вылазить не должен.

Comment: `e.target` - инициатор события, `e.currentTarget` элемент, на котором сработал обработчик. Может оставить обработчик только на родительском и там уже смотреть, кто куда что выделил?

Comment: @ThisMan была такая идея, но проблема в том, что там в любом случае в качестве таргета ставится первый ребенок, если выделять всего родителя, и хоть ты тресни. https://jsfiddle.net/fiorsaoirse/uLcwe5ty/26/

Comment: В принципе мою проблему решил бы длинный пробел в паренте перед дочерними элементами, но родитель должен быть ссылкой - т.е. там просто так не выделить нужный кусок первого дочернего элемента.

Comment: еще раз `e.target - инициатор события, e.currentTarget `, вместо `e.target` берите `e.currentTarget` - это элемент, на котором сработал обработчик

Comment: в вашем случае будет парент

Comment: @ThisMan, ок, попробую по-другому объяснить)
Допустим, из примера кода выше - я выделяю область в родительском контейнере, пкм - копировать, возникает событие "copy" - как мне узнать, какой именно дочерний элемент был скопирован? В случае, если текст был скопирован из 1 дочернего элемента, который "asdasd", мне надо к этому тексту дописать "JS one love" и вывести алертом. Если текст был скопирован из 2 элемента или из обоих элементов (т.е. все дочерние были выделены и скопированы" - мне не надо делать ничего, пусть останется, как есть, и алертом ничего не выводится.

Comment: Пока вижу только вариант сравнивать с значением дочерних и так определять, откуда было скопировано, но что-то бредово...

Comment: можно проверить что именно выделено, и если выделено что-то еще кроме нужного элемента - считать, что выделили родителя